# How do I find more monsters?

Tags: undertale

I am doing a Genocide run of Undertale and I've searched for a straight hour, but I can't find any monsters to fight! The ''But nobody came'' prompt has not shown up yet and neither has the ''Determination'' on the save points, but I cant find any monsters. I'm not sure what to do.

I have tried all the cheating techniques, Including cheat engine and I've tried revisiting areas, but nothing is working. The ''deer'' with all the stuff on its antlers doesn't even show up! I can't move onto Papyrus's fight without fighting two more monsters.

Comment: Note that if you killed Toriel without/before exhausting the kill counter, then you're not on a Genocide Route. I don't know how the game behaves in that particular situation, and it might be what you're experiencing.

Answer (score 3):

Once you get close to completely clearing out an area, the random encounter rate nosedives dramatically.  If you are serious about doing this run, it'll take some *determination* on your part.

Answer (score 2):

Zones only have so many monsters.  Once you kill them all, they're gone.  They are not infinite.  When doing a genocide run, 'but no one came' is a sign you need to go on to the next area.

If you used cheats, you may have altered the monster count, your question is a little unclear about that.  You shouldn't need two more monsters if the save point says 'Determination'.

Comment: I haven't got the ''But no one came'' in any areas, Period, And I meant the save doesnt say that, Its stuck one ''2 left''. :c

Comment: Then either you haven't done all of the encounters in the snow or you may have done something to your save.  That's all I can say based on what you've told us.